# Android вход в приложение по биометрии/пину

Tags: android, fingerprint

У нас есть много приложений где осуществляется вход через пин или биометрию. Банковские (ПриватБанк, Монобанк) и другие (Дия), уверен в других странах таких же много, к примеру ТинькоффБанк. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Я что-то не понял сначала говорите что у вас уже такое есть: "У нас есть много приложений где осуществляется вход через пин или биометрию", а потом спрашиваете: "Как такое реализовать?". Так у вас уже есть такой функционал или нет?))

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth

Comment: @EzioMercer, я думаю в этом подразумевается что есть вот куча приложений с таким функционалом, хочу такое же)

Comment: @Andrew А, вот оно что... Не с той интонацией прочёл :)